# can not find networkx module

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to use `networkx`'s `networkx.algorithms.community.quality` module to use `coverage()` But when I execute

```
from networkx.algorithms.community.quality import coverage
```

It shows

```
ImportError: No module named 'networkx.algorithms.community.quality'
```

Letter i found, my python only only find `networkx.algorithms.community.kclique` and `networkx.algorithms.community.tests` module. No `quality` module. My `networkx` version in 1.11, which is the latest.

Can anybody give me clue?

Comment: It looks like what you're after is in 2.0, which is approaching release.  It may be that you can find the `networkx.algorithms.community.quality` source code and use it, but it might not be compatible.

Comment: ya, did the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module doesn't exist on 1.11. I don't know if its functionality is somewhere else on 1.11 or if that functionality just doesn't exist on 1.11, but you're not going to find it in `networkx.algorithms.community.quality`